# Use of QImage InvertRgba function

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to use this function (InvertRgba) to invert all the pixels of an RGB image but unsure how to go about this, any ideas? The image I am using is loaded in main and then i want to call on this function to invert before saving it.

So far I do not have much to go with. Any help would be much apprecated, this is the code for loading the image:

```
 unsigned PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];     // Image loaded from file

    // If the file cannot be loaded ...
    if (!loadImage(PixelGrid, LogoFile))
    {
        // Display an error message
        cout << "Error loading file \"" << LogoFile << "\"" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "File \"" << LogoFile << "\" opened successfully" << endl;

      cout << " image succesfully mirrored" << mirrorImage << endl;
```

Comment: Do you want to **INVERT** the image (to obtain a negative like image) or **MIRROR** (something like rotation around the center) it? As per your source extract and question title I'm confused a bit.

Comment: The extract is taken from another part of my program which i am mirroring an image, in this peice i want to change all 1 values to 0 and vice versa.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?